# Html Table Fixed Columns (relatively positioned) Jerk on Firefox and Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox, microsoft-edge

I am working on an HTML table with multiple fixed columns working perfectly fine in google chrome, but in other browser like firefox, Microsoft edge, the fixed columns create a jerky behaviour when I try to scroll the table horizontally. I have also changed jquery part to plain/vanila javascript but still facing the same problem

```
$('tbody').scroll(function(e) { 

    $('thead').css("left", -$("tbody").scrollLeft()); 
    $('thead th.fixed:nth-child(n)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft());
    $('tbody').css("left", -$("thead").scrollLeft()); 
    var tbody = $('tbody td.fixed');

    for(var i=0; i < tbody.length; i++){
        tbody[i].style.left = $("tbody").scrollLeft() + 'px';

    }

});
```

Check this link for reference:
  http://jsfiddle.net/bzuasLcz/5591/